# Using parameters with FREETEXTTABLE changes output

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have this query

```
select top 10 * from FREETEXTTABLE([Venue], FullAddress,  'Canada')
```

which works fine, and produces results;

now if I'm calling this from code, and provide parameters, it is changed to

```
exec sp_executesql N'select top 10 * from FREETEXTTABLE([Venue], FullAddress,  ''@p'')',N'@p nvarchar(4000)',@p='Canada'
```

which produces no results whatsoever.
As far as I understand those 2 queries should produce identical output ? Or FREETEXTTABLE is especially picky about parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you shouldn't add the single quotes when using a `NVARCHAR` parameter. Try the following instead:

```
EXEC sp_executesql  N'select top 10 * from FREETEXTTABLE([Venue], FullAddress,  @p)',
                    N'@p nvarchar(4000)',
                    @p='Canada'
```

Comment: I don't, though, it happens when I execute the query from the code.  The 'EXEC sp_executesql' is taken from profiler.

Comment: @Eugene - Then its a problem with how you are executing your query *from code*. To be certain, does the query above return the expected result?

Comment: Yep, this "select top 10 * from FREETEXTTABLE([Venue], FullAddress,  'Canada')" works fine, when called from Management studio

Comment: The sp_executesql version returns nothing.

Comment: And yeah, your version works as well. However, I don't think this is something I can control.

Comment: @Eugene - Then something is wrong in the code that you are using to execute this query. Its higly likely that it is something that you can control